# Minimizing $ |Ax -b| $ using only algebraic arguments

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if I want to minimize $ |Ax -b| $  then I have to solve
$ A^T (Ax - b) = 0 $  because the error term  $ (Ax - b)$ suppose to be orthogonal to the columns of $A$ and the justification to this is typically given by geometrical arguments in 3 dimensions (Protagoras theorem). Can someone provide a pure algebraic argument why this is true ?

Comment: The solution here is purely algebraic (linear algebra) and it is based on orthogonal projections on to sublunar spaces [Prove uniqueness of solutions of different OLS matrix cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360477/prove-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-different-ols-matrix-cases)

Comment: I guess I don't understand why $ \nabla | Ax -b | = 2 A^T (Ax -b ) $

Comment: That is must likely the gradient of a function. That solution uses a little bit of Calculus. The link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4366126/121671)  you uses only linear algebra (geometric) methods.